# How do I customize what is shown for the value inside the stacked bar on a Dojo Chart

Tags: charts, dojo

Basically I have a dojo stacked bar chart where I have set these value to show the label on the bar:

```
"labels": true,
"labelStyle":"inside"
```

The value IS showing up, but i need to customize it by appending additional text to it.

I thought I could do something like the below, but it isnt working, I do not see my method _labelFunc get called:

```
p.labelFunc = lang.hitch({
                  self : this,                            
                  options : x.options
                  }, this._labelFunc);
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using lang.hitch a little incorrectly. I believe the first argument is supposed to just be the scope (e.g., this) and the second argument is a function or string name of the function if it already exists in the scope mentioned in argument 1.